# Overriding a defined CSS definition?

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new when it comes to CSS, trying to self-teach myself and I have stumbled upon an obstacle.

I took a random piece of HTML code with a CSS style reference sheet attached to it and I have tried to modify and analyze what exactly is going on there.

What I am trying to do override is this method:

```
#ds_div::before {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    content: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu4AAABkCAMAAADud0VvAAABYlBMV…7Th8ga23yve+pTdP/XHhwSAAAAAAj6/9oTRgAAAAAAAAAWAbhzwJPM92wRAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);}
```

the designated div is `<div id="ds_div">`. When I looked at the CSS style sheet there was no ::before method mentioned, therefore I did not know how to proceed. This is the only method that I want to change. This is the [link](https://crazylister.com/listing-assets/styles-1.05.css?mobileOptimized=true&uniqueHash=e46d51bcefc00ca4da2da2b8f62af3cf) To the style sheet.

What I want to know is how do I override only this method, if at all possible?

Comment: Is this the **only** stylesheet loaded? In some browsers when inspecting an element you can see which style sheet the rule is coming from.

Comment: That piece of code could be in the html in tags `<style> </style>`.

Comment: As @Terry has suggested you can check in inspector (There will be filename and line number right next to the declaration). Otherwise just override it by `#ds_div:before { content: '' !important; }`

Comment: @Terry I inspected the webpage's elements, and searched for 'stylesheet'. Haven't found another one

@pol Do you mean if I write inside the `<style>` tag a different method it will override the style sheet?

Comment: Expanding the <div id="ds_div"></div> in the HTML console will reveal the :before attribute beneath the opening tag, select it and you will get the styles in the console. As already suggested, you can override the style by #ds_div:before { content: ' ' !important; }

Comment: If you add the style inside of the page below the css reference, you should be able to overwrite the styles. CSS, works by reading the styles from the top down.  Anything lower in the stylesheet will overwrite anything higher up.  If you absolutely need to you can add !important after a style.  (display: block !important) and that will definitely overwrite the style as well, but it's not good form to use that often.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I guessed i asked a pretty novice question.
Just for general knowledge, why did my post get a down rank? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Probably someone who thought you would have found your answer more quickly by typing it into Google.

Answer (score 1):

CSS precedence like all code, I guess) is ordered from top to bottom, meaning whatever comes below over-rules what came previously.

The way your browser renders CSS will be over-ruled as soon as it comes across one of your stylesheets. If it isn't working it must be because some other stylesheet is being loaded after yours.

How to rectify this so that your stylesheet is loaded afterwards depends on the platform you're using (if any).

Like @Andrew Ice said, you can append `!important` onto a line of CSS and it'll over-rule other styles. This is mostly a bandaid solution, though. Try to just load the stylesheet properly if you can.

Comment: Well, order is one rule that determines which style wins, but not the only such one.